# d3js,when mouse drag the blank area,the force graph keeps jumping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have fllowing questions.

I used force graph and add zoom for it.

But when mouse drag the blank area,the force graph keeps jumping.

[like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Zfcx4ZrwMugemghByfO?p=preview)

How to make the graph do not jump?Thanks.

(I feel very sorry for my English.Thank you again.)

This is my zoom code.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Comment: It's an interesting one, trying to drag the graph purely horizontally at a small scale I see the second value in the `d3.event.transform` jumping a lot. If I zoom in the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a g element to your base SVG to group everything together (also appended any other elements to the g element instead of the svg), then in the zoomed() method, performed transforms on that g element instead of on the svg element:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.call(zoom);

var g = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");
```

Zoom method:

```
function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Also, when setting up node listeners, stop event propagation for the 'mousedown' event, like so:

```
var node = g.selectAll(".node")
.data(force.nodes())
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.on("mouseover", mouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout)
.on("click", click)
.on("dblclick", dblclick)
.on("mousedown", function(d) { 
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
})
.call(force.drag)
.on('click', connectedNodes);
```

[Here's the working example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/NJpmQW3pLsz5mSKvrz40?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much.And I also want to know how to find the problem?Is programming experience?Or often practice?Or see more examples?Because I can not find the way that the zoom event on 'svg' and modify the 'g' attributes.